# moving to the top of the stack (parent screen) in nested navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, react-navigation

I have multiple `createStackNavigator` for different screens, and I use them in my `createBottomTabNavigator` so all the screens are reachable from other screens, the problem is when I navigate to Home screen in my `createBottomTabNavigator` if I open any of the other screens like contact screen  `createStackNavigator`, then if I navigate to profile screen in my `createBottomTabNavigator`, and then if I go back to the home screen again, then instead of seeing the home screen, I still see the contact screen (since its on top of the stack) I have to click on home again so it takes me there.

This is because I am using nested navigations, I am not quite sure how to navigate directly to Home or any other screens in `createBottomTabNavigator` and not to any screens in `createStackNavigator`.

this is an example of what I mean:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="SearchScreen"
        component={SearchScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="ContactScreen" component={ContactScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="FavoriteScreen" component={FavoriteScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const HelpStack = createStackNavigator();
const Help = () => {
  return (
    <HelpStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Help"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <HelpStack.Screen
        name="SearchScreen"
        component={SearchScreen}
      />
      <HelpStack.Screen name="ContactScreen" component={ContactScreen} />
      <HelpStack.Screen name="FavoriteScreen" component={FavoriteScreen} />
    </HelpStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator();
const Profile = () => {
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="CreateProfile"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
     <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="SearchScreen"
        component={SearchScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="ContactScreen" component={ContactScreen} />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="FavoriteScreen" component={FavoriteScreen} />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const MainTabs = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Home}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Help"
      component={Help}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Profile "
      component={Profile}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

So I go to Home component and then from there go to profile screen, then if  go to Help screen, then if I click back at Home, it will take me to profile screen instead of Home screen, how can I make sure this doesnt happen because ita bit confusing. I have the `createBottomTabNavigator` tabs visible in every other screen, so this is why I need to move directly to the root screen.

Comment: Hi, perhaps something like `popToTop` to return to the root? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/

Comment: @IronMan I would be able to use it if I was using a button, but the tabs are in the createBottomTabNavigator and I think from there I have to do something. because I have the createBottomTabNavigator also visible in every page.